# $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\cap_{x\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ in integral schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $X$ be an integral scheme with a generic point $\xi$.

I understand:

1. For every affine open $V\subset X$, $\text{Frac}\mathcal{O}_X(V)\cong \mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}$
2. For every open $U\subset X$ and $x\in X$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}$ are injective.
3. For every affine open $U\subset X$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\cap_{x\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ (regarding both sides as subrings of $\mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}$)

But in Qing Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" Prop. 4.18 on page 65, it is claimed that (3) is true for every open $U$ (not necessarily affine). The given reasoning is "by covering $U$ with open affine subsets".

Up until now I managed to fill in the details when such reasoning was given, but not here. What is the accurate explanation of the reduction to the affine case here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathcal O_X(U) \subset \cap_{x \in U} \mathcal O_{X,x}$ is obvious from 2.

For the other direction let $U=\bigcup_i U_i$ be an affine open cover and let $s \in \cap_{x \in U} \mathcal O_{X,x} \subset \cap_{x \in U_i} \mathcal O_{X,x}$.

By the result for affine opens, you get $s \in \mathcal O_X(U_i)$ for all $i$. Clearly $s$ agrees with itself on the intersections $U_i \cap U_j$, i.e. by the sheaf axiom it extends to a section on $\mathcal O_X(U)$.